# Issue to set bean value coming from a bean in a jsf page

Tags: jsf, jstl

there is this bean in this jsf page which contains value of 3

```
#{beanValueFromBean.id}
```

When I try to set this value through jstl like this

```
<c:set value="#{beanValueFromBean.id}" target="#{backingBean}" property="responseId" />
```

It's just not setting the value when I call

```
#{backingBean.responseId} <!--displays blank -->
```

if I set it this way it will work

```
 <c:set value="3" target="#{backingBean}" property="responseId" />
```

I am sure it's a matter of jsf life cycle, I've trie different ways to be able to set this value, even applying to a ui:param variable like this

```
<ui:param name="god" value="#{beanValueFromBean.id}"/>
```

#{god} prints 3, but this variable won't set this value to the #{backingBean.responseId}

I appreciate your help.

**Edit**

I also attempted to put a @PostContruct annotation in the setter method of the backing bean

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void setResponseId(String responseId) {
    this.responseId = responseId;
 }
```

But that didn't work

Comment: Suspicious upvote within 21 minutes of the question being posted and a question of a fairly low quality

Comment: I'd say suspicious downvote @Kukeltje

Comment: No not suspicious… quality is low, little research, bad tagging, no mcve etc… so valid downvote